# How does this code to vaidate email work?

Tags: iphone

This code validates your email field, but I can't understand how it works.

```
NSString *e = email.text;
NSString *emailRegEx =@"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
@"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
@"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
@"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
@"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
@"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
@"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";

NSPredicate *regExPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
BOOL myStringMatchesRegEx = [regExPredicate evaluateWithObject:e];
NSLog(@"myStringMatchesRegEx = %d ",myStringMatchesRegEx);
```

Comment: Did you use regular expressions before? If yes, take it apart by reading it bit by bit. If not, I suggest searching for some tutorials on regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats one huge regular expression :)

Basically, the `NSPredicate` states that it wants to match itself (which is an `NSString` in the end) with a regular expression (are you familiar with Regular Expressions?) and returns a YES/NO response if the given NSString (which is the email.text) matches that regular expression.

In essence, its making sure that the email text is valid according to the massive regular expression (which I will not go into as it would take hours to get my head around).

Comment: can u tell me some logic to validate email without this kind of regular expression

Comment: The regex is so complex *because* it's not trivial to correctly validate an email under all circumstances. What do you want instead? Nasty bunch of nested if-statements?

Comment: yeah which anyone can understand for eg; string has suffix :com or in or like this normal logic

Comment: Like Martin said, email address are massively complex, emails do not net com in them (.net address for example), the email address spec itself it huge and not to be underestimated, if you are serious about valid email addresses, use this regex